# how to refer sns arn from terraform code in a lambda python py file?

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-sns

my lambda python uses SNS topic arn. But this sns arn id is generated from terraform code. Is there way to refer it somehow in python lambda code?

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:            
        #some code                  
        publish_vote(vote, voter)

    except:
        #some code
    
    return {'statusCode': 200, 'body': '{"status": "success"}'}

def publish_vote(vote, voter):
    sns = boto3.client('sns', region_name='us-east-1')

    sns.publish(
        TopicArn='arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:025416187662:erjan',
        Message='""',
        MessageAttributes={
            "vote": {
                "DataType": "String",
                "StringValue": vote,
            },
            "voter": {
                "DataType": "String",
                "StringValue": voter,
            }          
        }
    )
```

SNS terraform code:

```
resource "aws_sns_topic" "vote_sns" {
  name = "erjan-sns"
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "vote_sns_access_policy" {
  arn = aws_sns_topic.vote_sns.arn

  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.vote_sns_access_policy.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "vote_sns_access_policy" {
  policy_id = "__default_policy_ID"

  statement {
    #some stuff code 
    }

}


output "sns_arn_erjan" {
  value       = aws_sns_topic.vote_sns.arn
  description = "aws full sns topic"
}
```

Comment: Pass it into the lambda as part of its [`environment`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function#environment)

Comment: dont know how to do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a Terraform object into an AWS Lambda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70708036/how-to-get-a-terraform-object-into-an-aws-lambda-environment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your terraform code does not have code for creating the lambda function itself. Are you creating it manually? If yes, then first create that as well using terraform. A basic example is mentioned [here](https://%20https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function#basic-example)

Within the definition, there is an argument for environment. Use that to define your env variables as:

```
  environment {
    variables = {
      SNS_ARN = aws_sns_topic.vote_sns.arn # Arn from the defined sns resource.
    }
  }
```

Then refer the same in your python code as:

```
import os
SNS_ARN = os.environ.get("SNS_ARN")
...
```

Alternatively, you could also consider using [AWS SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-getting-started.html)

Comment: Hardcoding the SNS_ARN in the env is basically just as good / bad as hardcoding it within python. Instead the value should be something like `aws_sns_topic.vote_sns.arn`.

Comment: I had missed to add it. Thanks for spotting, have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For your information:
I see you have already solved this problem, but I have one suggestion.

The lambda function can refer to the topic ARN by putting the ARN as a parameter into Parameter Store with Terraform.

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "vote_sns" {
  name  = "sns_arn_erjan"
  type  = "String"
  value = aws_sns_topic.vote_sns.arn
}
```

[aws_ssm_parameter | Resources | hashicorp/aws | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssm_parameter)

The lambda function can refer to the parameter stored in Parameter Store using boto3.

[get_parameter - SSM — Boto3 Docs 1.26.54 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.get_parameter)

Comment: oh i see, param store can be used as well. thx u